# Which querySelector on <paper-toolbar> is better?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

```
var toolbar = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('#main-toolbar')
```

---

```
var toolbar = document.querySelector('#main-toolbar');
```

---

```
<paper-toolbar id="main-toolbar">
```

1) why does `document.querySelector` work on `paper-toolbar` when it's a shadow dom element? or another way to put it... why does it work on a element that is in local dom?

2) since both of these `querySelector` work, which is better to use?

Comment: Is the toolbar outside of a Polymer element declaration?

Comment: it's in index.html....so no custom element getting stamped. However, it is inside a `<template is="dom-bind" id="app">`

Comment: Could also use this.$.main-toolbar if you are in the scope of the Polymer element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toolbar is not inside a polymer element.
You can juste use document.querySelector('#main-toolbar');
No need to use Polymer API here (polymer element are HTML elements).
The polymer API is useful to access the shadow/shady DOM (inside your polymer elements).